# How to create a server for sending and fetching longitude and latitude positions?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I have a basic application that reads the longitude and latitude position from the phone. Now how do i send these longitude and latitude positions to another android device having the same application running? I know the other phone requires fetching of the positions from a server. But how do i create this server and then send and fetch data from it? Just want to give a little presentation so not looking for much hi-fi stuff!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy a server to store the data and any device can obtain the data.

[Example connect with php mysql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)